# How can I get every event video time updated?

Tags: javascript, video

In javascript HTMLMediaElement: timeupdate event, is there any way to get every time_update_event?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the timeupdate event:**
This will give you events [between 4 and 66 times a second](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event).

```js
const videoTimeUpdateHandler = function (e) {
  e.currentTime // the current time
}

const videoElement = document.getElementById('video'); // or `new Video()`
videoElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdateHandler);
```

**Manually polling the media elements currentTime at your desired frequency:**
If you want a higher frequency of events than the user agent gives you, manually poll the media elements currentTime property like so:

```js
const videoCurrentTimeIntervalHandler = function (currentTime) {
  currentTime // the current time
}

const videoElement = document.getElementById('video'); // or `new Video()`
const videoCurrentTimeInterval = setInterval(videoCurrentTimeIntervalHandler(videoElement.currentTime), 50); // here we poll the currentTime property every 50ms
```

Don't forget to remove your event listener or clear your interval like so:

```js
videoElement.removeEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdateHandler);
```

or

```js
clearInterval(videoCurrentTimeInterval);
```

Comment: Thank you I understand.